# What is a fast way to darken the vertices I'm rendering?

Tags: opengl, lighting, lwjgl

To make a lighting system for a voxel game, I need to specify a darkness value per vertex. I'm using GL_COLOR_MATERIAL and specifying a color per vertex, like this:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);


glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glColor3f(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f);
glTexCoord2f(...);
glVertex3f(...);

glColor3f(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);    
glTexCoord2f(...);
glVertex3f(...);

glColor3f(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f);        
glTexCoord2f(...);
glVertex3f(...);

glColor3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
glTexCoord2f(...);
glVertex3f(...);

glEnd();
```

This is working, but with many quads it is very slow.. I'm using display lists too. Any good ideas in how to make vertices darker?

Comment: You need to switch to [vertex buffers](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here, almost certainly, is not that you're "darkening" your vertices by specifying the vertex colors. The problem is more likely to do with how you're rendering everything in general -- you appear to be using immediate mode in your code sample, and although you claim to be using display lists which are somewhat better, you're likely going to want to switch to [VBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) as suggested by bobobobo.

However, your performance issue could be somewhere else entirely, for example, you may not be culling your voxels as aggressively as you could. You're not providing enough information to answer the question about your poor render performance, though.